# C++ Error: 'x' is not a constant expression, how to fix?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, logic, constexpr

To make it short, here is a minimal example:

```
struct C {
    const int X = 2;
    int y = 2;
};
void f(C* x) {
    switch(x->y) {
        case x->X: printf("%d", 42); break;
        case 123: printf("foo");
    }
}
int main()
{
    C c;
    f(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the compiler complaining `error: 'x' is not a constant expression` and how to fix it?

Comment: Try declaring C::X as static constexpr.  And then use C::X in the case instead of x->X

Comment: You can't use `x->X` as case for the switch.

Comment: @DarthRubik I don't want static variables when it is not really necessary.

Comment: @Nacho Why is this not possible?

Comment: Look at dasblinkenlight's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Case labels inside `switch` accept only compile-time constant expressions. `x->X` is *not* a constant expression; hence it could not be used as a `case` label.

Replace the `switch` statement with an `if` to fix this problem:

```
if (x->y == x->X) {
    printf("%d", 42);
} else if (x->y == 123) {
    printf("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In main, you declare an instance of C and pass it to f. According to the definition of f, it does not guarantee that c does not get changed - and main has no way to verify it.
I think f needs to be `f(C * const x);`

Answer (score 0):

The given code (modulo formatting)

```
struct C
{
    int const x = 2;
    int y = 2;
};
```

… means this:

```
struct C
{
    int const x;
    int y;

    C(): x( 2 ), y( 2 ) {}
};
```

… i.e. the members are initialized by each constructor.

You can even override that initialization in a user defined constructor:

```
struct S
{
    int const x = 2;

    S(): x( 3 ) {}
};
```

Here in every instance `x` will be 3.

And so `x` isn't a compile time constant. It's very much a run time thing. And as such it can't be used as a `case` label in a `switch`, because a `case` label must be a value known at compile time. In turn because the `switch` construct is designed to be efficiently implemented as simple array indexing (a computed jump) when the value range permits that.

---

One simple fix is to define the relevant value as a compile time constant. Either as a `static` or `enum` value inside the class. Or outside the class.

---

Another possible fix is to use an `if`-`else` ladder instead of a `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Case accepts Constant Expression,like 2 or 'a'.And Const just define an unchanging variant.